# Schedule task when other app is using network

Tags: android

In my app I show an persistent notification on status bar in which real time data is shown. However I cannot just make a poller for the real time data because it will cost too much battery. What I am thinking is that I update the data whenever some other app is using the network. So that network requests are batched and battery consumption will be reduced. Is there an api in Android to do such scheduling? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve scheduling tasks by using the `AlarmManager` class, you can have look at the [offical doc](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However the key of the question is schedule a task when other apps are using the network. So that it doesn't cost too much battery. Actually I just found GCMNetworkManager might be useful.

Comment: ah, right! yeah, just had look at that, seems legit :)